# If $f(x,y)=x$ , then is it true that $f$ is a closed map?

Tags: analysis

If $f(x,y)=x$ , then is it true that $f$ is a closed map?
I think it is not true, but I can't find any counter example!

Comment: Why do you think it's not true?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f(\{(x,y): xy=1\}$. The im age is $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$.